# How do i implement ContextMenu for ListView having SeparatedListAdapter?

Tags: android, android-listview, contextmenu

I am showing some data in list view in sections using [`SepatateListAdapter` from this post](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/)

My code is as follows:

```
ListView photos_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.photos_list);

separate_adapter = new SeparatedListAdapter(this);

AddedPhotosAdapter one_adapter = new AddedPhotosAdapter(this, R.layout.row_acc_info , photos_instagram);
separate_adapter.addSection(" Section1 ", one_adapter);

AddedPhotosAdapter two_adapter = new AddedPhotosAdapter(this, R.layout.row_acc_info , photos_fb);
separate_adapter.addSection(" Section2 ", two_adapter);

AddedPhotosAdapter three_adapter = new AddedPhotosAdapter(this, R.layout.row_acc_info , photos_picasa);
separate_adapter.addSection(" Section3 ", thee_adapter);

photos_list.setAdapter(separate_adapter);
```

i registered for contextmenu also

```
registerForContextMenu(photos_list);
```

this is the code for contextmenu creation and item selected from menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.photos_list) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        Log.i(TAG, "*********position******" +info.position);
        Object item = separate_adapter.getItem(info.position);
        PhotosInfo total = (PhotosInfo) item ;          
        menu.setHeaderTitle(total.getPhoto_Name());

        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Delete photo account");  
        menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Cancel"); 
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 1: 
            break;
        case 2:                  
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

this is the code i am using for list view with SeparateListAdapter i am getting this error here `FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(9228): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
 E/AndroidRuntime(9228):    at com.colours.pipemedia.photos.PhotosMain.onCreateContextMenu(PhotosMain.java:170)`

this is the line causing for error in code

```
PhotosInfo total = (PhotosInfo) item ;
```

I am using this code for single adapter it's working fine. but if i use with separate list adapter its giving error. what is the solution for this requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using [this `SeparatedListAdapter`](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2008/08/18/separating-lists-with-headers-in-android-09/) (although, you should have posted this link, because SeparatedListAdapter is not a standard component and you should always provide the code relevant to your problem. I edited your post to include the link)

The problem is, as you can see in `getItem()` if the parameter is `0` it will just return you a `String` section name, otherwise it will return you an item of type one of your `Adapter`s holds.

So, to avoid the exception you should just check the type returned like so:

```
Object item = separate_adapter.getItem(info.position);
if (item instanceof String) {
    // It's a section title, do something about it
} else {
    // It's an actual item from one of the adapters
    PhotosInfo total = (PhotosInfo) item ;          
    menu.setHeaderTitle(total.getPhoto_Name());

    menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Delete photo account");  
    menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Cancel");
}
```

Comment: yes i am using that adapter only. then how to solve this issue.